# Height 100% Property Clipping Column

Tags: css

I have a site which is structured with three columns, and each column must be 100% height of the external wrapper (ie, the page).

I have set html, body and all the columns to:

```
height: 100%;
```

However the third column is clipping the content and i can't figure out why. I've had a look at similar questions on SO but none seem to fix my problem.

I've set up a jsfiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/rTXt6/

I'm sure its a simple solution but its driving me mad and I hope someone can help.

Edit: To be a little clearer, height: 100% seems to set the height to 100% the height of the browser window, it doesn't resize to take account of its content which may run longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a pure HTML/CSS fix and updated jsfiddle to show it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rTXt6/7/)

Basically I've just nested each div in the previous one up until the last (rightcol), and given each child div a lower percentage width.

```
<div>LeftCol
    <div>CenterCol
         <div>RightCol
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for everyone's input as usual :)

Answer (score 0):

With css floats you should use a clearfix like [this one](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).

I just added to your code :

**Html**

```
<div class="cf"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

Clearfix from the bellow link.

See updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/rTXt6/2/)

Comment: This does the same as original [http://jsfiddle.net/rTXt6/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/rTXt6/3/). You just removed text and it looks like real solution :)

Comment: Hmm I see, misunderstand your question, updating soon ;)

Answer (score 0):

After spending bit of time it seems I've found solution. Set `min-height:100%` instead of `height:100%` to all your inner containers of your `#container` div. [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rTXt6/4/)

Comment: Hmm, yeah I tried this too, but I still think that with a clearfix, your container got the height of the bigger div (here `#right`) so it should do the trick...

Comment: @Morpeus Doesn't work I'm afraid (or rather doesn't do as I want it to), as the first two columns don't stretch to match the now correct right column.

Comment: @Dan in that case it seems you'll have to use javascript

Comment: @Morpheus yeah that's what it's looking like. Appreciate your help though :) just looking at http://www.impressivewebs.com/equal-height-columns-with-javascript-full-version/

Comment: See this little [example](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/rTXt6/6/), it'll be fine in every case but ofc if you need all columns to have the same height you should use javascript...